# I get GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT for the second FBO I create but not the first

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo

I had an OpenGL application with one FBO besides the default frame buffer. Everything worked fine.

Then I tried to add a second FBO, using the same code as I used for the first one, and suddenly it does not work anymore. Only for the second FBO I get the following status: `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`

My first FBO is still working as intended with no problems whatsoever. I double and triple checked that both FBO's are generated with the same code. I even went over the OpenGL wiki pages at www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/ again to make sure I used all of these OpenGL methods correctly.

I check for OpenGL errors after every single OpenGL function call.

```
public void createFBO(int width, int height) {
    glNameFbo = glGenFramebuffers();
    checkForGLErrors();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, glNameFbo);
    checkForGLErrors();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    checkForGLErrors();
    glNameTex = GL11.glGenTextures();
    checkForGLErrors();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glNameTex);
    checkForGLErrors();
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    checkForGLErrors();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    checkForGLErrors();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    checkForGLErrors();

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, glNameTex, 0);
    checkForGLErrors();
    glDrawBuffers(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    checkForGLErrors();

    int fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    checkForGLErrors();
    if(fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        System.err.println("Error when creating FBO: "+getFrameBufferStatus(fboStatus));
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    checkForGLErrors();
}
```

Thanks to anybody who can lead me in the right direction!

Comment: This was a copy-paste error. In my actual code the variables were named w and h and I wrote them out for the question but obviously overlooked that one occurence.

Comment: There is no obvious issue in this part of the code.

Comment: And you are using the same `width` and `height` for both FBOs?

Comment: You are correct. The width and height were actually zero for the second FBO that I created. That was the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I am stupid. As was pointed out in the comments it turned out that the problem was with the "width" and "height" that I passed to my FBO creation methods. My first FBO was created with the window size but my second FBO had 0 passed for both dimensions.

The code from the question seems to be fine.